# Api Gateway Model validation incorrectly validates request when content is string instead of JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I added a Model to my API Gateway. When I send a POST request with the body containing a string (instead of valid JSON) the Model validates the request. I was expecting it to be rejected.

I've tried these two cases showing the problem:

1. The Model will validate "A_STRING" (incorrect behaviour)
2. The Model will validate "A_STRING"{} (incorrect behaviour)
3. The Model will fail {"A_STRING"} (correct behaviour)

I am testing the API Gateway directly from the AWS console (see attached screenshot), here are the logs for one example:

```
Execution log for request b2b825b4-4fb2-43e6-935b-0781264eb5df
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : Starting execution for request: b2b825b4-4fb2-43e6-935b-0781264eb5df
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /TrainingNotif
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : Method request path: {}
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : Method request query string: {}
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : Method request headers: {}
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : Method request body before transformations: "A_STRING"
Mon Aug 17 21:45:42 UTC 2020 : Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
```

If it helps here is my model:

```json
{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "required": 
  [
    "trainingSiteRequester",
    "employeeTrainingList"
  ],
  "properties": 
  {
    "trainingSiteRequester": 
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "employeeTrainingList": 
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": 
      {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "type": "object",
        "required": 
        [
          "id",
          "trainingURL",
          "dueDate"
        ],
        "properties": 
        {
          "trainingURL": 
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "dueDate": 
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": 
          {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And to be complete here is my CloudFormation code to attach the model to the API Gateay:

```yaml
PostMethod:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
    HttpMethod: POST
    RequestValidatorId: !Ref TrainingNotificationRequestValidator
    RequestModels:
      application/json: !Ref TrainingNotificationRequestModel
    Integration:
      Credentials: !GetAtt TrainingNotificationsAPIGatewayRole.Arn
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
      IntegrationResponses:
        - SelectionPattern: 200
          StatusCode: 200
        - SelectionPattern: 429
          StatusCode: 429
      PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
      RequestParameters:
        integration.request.querystring.Action: "'SendMessage'"
        integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${ReceivedRequestsSNS}'"
        integration.request.querystring.Message: "method.request.body"
      RequestTemplates:
        application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
      Type: AWS
      Uri:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:apigateway:"
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - ":sns:action/Publish"
    MethodResponses:
      - StatusCode: 200
      - StatusCode: 429
      - StatusCode: 500
    ResourceId: !Ref TrainingNotificationsAPIGatewayResources
    RestApiId: !Ref TrainingNotificationsAPIGateway

# Request Model
TrainingNotificationRequestModel:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Model
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref TrainingNotificationsAPIGateway
    ContentType: application/json
    Name: TrainingNotificationRequestModel
    Schema:
      $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#'
      additionalProperties: false
      required:
        - trainingSiteRequester
        - employeeTrainingList
      properties:
        trainingSiteRequester:
          type: string
        employeeTrainingList:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            additionalProperties: false
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
              trainingURL:
                type: string
              dueDate:
                type: string
            required:
              - id
              - trainingURL
              - dueDate

TrainingNotificationRequestValidator:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref TrainingNotificationsAPIGateway
    Name: TrainingNotificationRequestValidator
    ValidateRequestBody: true
```

[image]

Comment: You are not sending the same body though, 
you are sending "{\"employeeTrainingList\":} from js

Comment: @dsharew thanks for pointing that out. I think some data got lost with my copy-and-pasting. I've updated the question with correct logs. The request should be reject by the model because the trainingSiteRequester property is missing (in both).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, the Model's schema didn't have a Type property.

Adding type : object makes the model reject anything that isn't json (as expected) and makes the model run validation against anything that is JSON.

To be honest I found this through trial and error, so I'm not 100% sure as to the why of my answer, but it works.